# Retrieve all words related to one WordNet

Tags: python, wordnet

I want to get all the words related to 'food' with WordNet

```
import nltk
from nltk.corpus import wordnet as wn
food = wn.synsets('food')

for synset in food:
   for lemma in synset.lemmas():
       print lemma.name()
```

With this code I got this :

```
food
nutrient
food
solid_food
food
food_for_thought
intellectual_nourishment
```

What I'm trying to achieve is something like this

food 
-> solid_food
-> liquid_food
-> powder_food

And something that goes on and on recursively like
solid_food
-> vegetables
-> meat ...

In short I'm trying to access the hierarchy of Wordnet from one word : 'food'.
How can I do this, any idea ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can explore the hierarchy  by following the relation `Hyponymy` that take you from the general term to the specific term:

> Hyponymy shows the relationship between the more general terms
>   (hypernyms) and the more specific instances of it (hyponyms).
>
> [ref](https://www.google.dz/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwi3prO-4uPJAhWBvxoKHQbBBxQQFggdMAE&url=https%3A%2F%2Fen.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2FHyponymy_and_hypernymy&usg=AFQjCNHwsQy5Uy_EPHp4YAYlR0Pu1_Jo5w&sig2=6IK9a_y9BExLLGUSwoxhFg)

```
>>>  food[1].hyponyms()
[Synset('fish.n.02'), Synset('slop.n.04'), Synset('coconut.n.01'), 
Synset('baked_goods.n.01'), Synset('yogurt.n.01'), Synset('breakfast_food.n.01'), Synset('seafood.n.01'), Synset('cheese.n.01'), Synset('pasta.n.02'), Synset('meat.n.01'), Synset('leftovers.n.01'), Synset('butter.n.01'), Synset('produce.n.01'), Synset('convenience_food.n.01'), Synset('fresh_food.n.01'), Synset('junk_food.n.01'), Synset('dika_bread.n.01'), Synset('loaf.n.02'), Synset('chocolate.n.02'), Synset('health_food.n.01')]
```

Keep using synonyms too.

Comment: it's not exactly the hierarchy that I was hoping to find but it's not your fault ;)